# Asserting async exception and paramName with FluentAssertions

Tags: c#, testing, fluent-assertions

I'm using `FluentAssertions`.

For a sync test, I can write this:

```cs
action.Should().Throw<ArgumentNullException>().And.ParamName.Should().Be("foo");
```

For an async test, I do this:

```cs
await action.Should().ThrowAsync<ArgumentNullException>();
```

Is there a convenience method to also assert `ParamName`, or must I do it manually by wrapping in a try-catch?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library, but I'd think it would be something like `(await action.Should().ThrowAsync<ArgumentNullException>()).And.ParamName.Should().Be("foo");`

Comment: @DavidL Yep that was it, thanks.

Comment: Since FA 6.0 you can also use `.WithParameterName("foo")`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try capturing the exception assertion and you should be ale to continue the assertion as you would have with synchronous code.

```
//...

var error = await act.Should().ThrowAsync<ArgumentNullException>();

error.And.ParamName.Should().Be("foo");

//...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it fully fluent with `WaitASync().Result`:

```
act.Should().ThrowAsync<ArgumentNullException>().WaitAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result.And.ParamName.Should().Be("foo");
```